# Cannot run configuration PHP

Tags: server, nginx, php7

I have installed nginx1.13.1, and php7.0.18, I tried to run configuration PHP  page on my website server but it is 404 not found error. Would you please help me how to configuration

The Nginx Configuration ( /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf ) as following:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name example.com;

   # charset koi8-r;   
   # access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
     location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
     #   fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That `fastcgi_pass` line and `fastcgi_index` line you have commented out in the PHP section of your config is what makes PHP work.  Uncomment those lines, restart nginx, and it should start working provided you update the `fastcgi_pass` line to point to the PHP socket on your system (refer to the config for PHP for the proper path).

As for the 404s, please refer to `/var/log/nginx/error.log` and make sure that you set the `root` in your server configuration outside of the locations to where your PHP files are actually stored - this needs to be done so NGINX knows where to look for your files.

Comment: @C.Nguyen You're welcome, note I've updated my answer since I noticed you said something about 404s, and you're missing a 'root' directive for your entire server block.

Comment: It's very nice of you. I have changed Nginx to Apache. I will  try to run Nginx again some other times. Thanks